# Salted or unsalted butter

Tags: frying

I'm a fan of James Martin and have no problem with the amount of butter that he uses.  However, I'm totally unsure what type of butter to use!  Salted or unsalted?

Comment: What are you making? You tagged this frying - I guess you're sauteeing/frying things?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how much salt you like in your food.  Most recipes are written for unsalted butter because it makes it easier to control the amount of salt.  If your butter is salted, you can use it and it will probably still taste good.  Although, you may need to reduce salt a bit elsewhere in the recipe if it uses a lot of butter.  When in doubt, go with unsalted, then add salt as needed.

Comment: I disagree with the statement that most recipes are written for unsalted butter, it's just the opposite - especially in the USA. In the UK many baking recipes use unsalted butter, however you can make no assumptions.